# How can I validate some specific fields that exist in my request.body using Joi?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm writing an API for editing that document.
Assuming I just want to edit field description, I would pass it to my request.body.description = "new description" . So I only want to validate that field ( description ).

In sum, I just want to validate the fields which is gonna are edited (exist in request.body).
Please tell me how to handle this ?
Thank you in advance !

[This is my joi schema for validating a new Package document with all fields required.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXASD.png)